# Synchronise linux dual boot and virtual machine

Tags: linux, sync

I have a heavy "desktop replacement" laptop and a lighter (and weaker) laptop. I want to have Linux installed on the heavy laptop as a dual boot for every day use, and a virtual machine on the lighter laptop to use on the go. What is the best way to keep the contents (software and files) of these installations synchronised? Git? Connect both on Bluetooth and do a diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app that might suit your purpose is Unison. It is explicitly designed to keep two directory trees in sync, with some extras such as excluding files from sync. It is available from the Debian repository (not sure about RPM-based distros, but you might be lucky).

Git might do the trick, but it comes with various types of overhead. First, you would need to commit everything you want synched, every time you sync. Then, git keeps a complete history of all file versions you ever committed, requiring more disk space.

Comment: Unison would be perfect for this sort of setup.  If you don't to schedule it manually or run it as a cron, you can use it in part with lsyncd to have a sort or open source Dropbox setup.

Comment: Although I was very interested in unison, I went for git with git annex in the end. Thanks for the reply.